# JSP within C# WebBrowser

Tags: c#, jsp, browser

I have a Windows Forms Application which used the WebBrowser class to access a website. The only problem I am encountering is the execution of JSP scripts in the browser. Is there anyway to solve this?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://notions.okuda.ca/2009/06/11/calling-javascript-in-a-webbrowser-control-from-c/
Does this one help?

Answer (score 0):

What an odd combination.  I can't see why you'd mix .NET and Java EE in this way.

You'll have to add a servlet/JSP engine to render your JSPs when their URL is invoked; IIS will have to be told how to bridge over to it.

UPDATE: The new information clarifies things a bit.  Are you sure you don't mean "applet"?

You're invoking a method on a JavaScript object in the widgets.js that isn't available.  You're missing some JavaScript.